# Betheme Wordpress How to hide or Remove Admin menu Items

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, themes

I am using currently Betheme Wordpress and I want to remove admin menu Betheme `li` Items

Kindly view the image what i want is also defined in image  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution and its workig 100%

1st step open this file `projectName/wp-admin/admin.php`

then

2nd Step in footer of the page insert this code

```
<style> li a[href="admin.php?page=be-websites"] { display: none !important; } </style>
```

Enjoy My Solution ...

Answer (score -1):

Go to theme editor and remove the line that makes the item  to display in the admin panel.

Comment: thanks for answer but i want know proper answer because i have tried lots thing in theme but i did'nt get to hide menu items Betheme if you know then send me proper path .

Comment: Please make changes in the $ label  which is the array.

Comment: thanks but your answer not helped me i want to customize Betheme  .